# Set WPF Image source from List<T> based on combo box selection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a SearchResponse class that is returned to my viewmodel.

```
public class SearchResponse
{
    public ICollection<SearchResult> Results { get; private set; }
    public string OriginalSearchTerm { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeTaken { get; private set; }

    public SearchResponse(ICollection<SearchResult> results, string originalSearchTerm, TimeSpan timeTaken)
    {
        Results = results;
        OriginalSearchTerm = originalSearchTerm;
        TimeTaken = timeTaken;
    }
}
```

A listbox is bound to `SearchResponse.Results` with each item containing an image for the thumbnail. `SearchResult` looks like this:

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ThumbnailImage> ThumbnailPaths { get; set; }

    public SearchResult()
    {
    }

    public SearchResult(string title, string description, string path, ICollection<ThumbnailImage> thumbnailPaths)
    {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        Path = path;
        ThumbnailPaths = thumbnailPaths;
    }
}
```

And here is `ThumbnailImage` (ThumbnailSize is an enum):

```
public class ThumbnailImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ThumbnailSize ThumbnailSize { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public ThumbnailImage()
    {

    }

    public ThumbnailImage(ThumbnailSize thumbnailSize, string path)
    {
        ThumbnailSize = thumbnailSize;
        Path = path;
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a ComboBox bound to an enum of thumbnail sizes with the intention that when the user selects a size the thumbnail images in the search results immediately change accordingly. So when this happens I need to query the `ICollection<ThumbnailImage>` for the correct filepath, update the image width and height (fixed width/height for each thumbnail size) and apply the changes to the entire list of results.

```
<ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ThumbnailSizesFromEnum}}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentThumbnailSize}">
        </ComboBox>
```

I have a working bound `CurrentThumbnail` property as shown above.

Can anyone suggest the best (or at least a good) way to approach this. At the moment I just have a headache form reading too much trying to find a solution.
I wonder if I should make use of a Command, a Value Converter or maybe a StyleTrigger but either way I really need some pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having some difficulty following the hierarchy of items that you're displaying, but I believe the answer you're looking for is simple: you must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the class (or classes) that contain properties that you will be changing in response to a change in `CurrentThumbnail`. As I understand your question, you're not in doubt about how to update the thumbnail data when the currently selected size changes, you're just wondering how to telegraph the fact that you've changed the data to your data binding. That's what `INotifiyPropertyChanged` is for.

For example, this version of `ThumbnailImage` will telegraph changes in the `Path` property to any XAML attribute that is bound to `Path`:

```
public class ThumbnailImage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _path;

    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _path)
            {
                _path = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Path");

                    PropertyChanged(this, args);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I would also suggest that you make sure the hierarchy of classes that you're using to represent the data that is displayed (all of these classes are essentially part of your view model) should match the hierarchy of your XAML. It's hard to tell because you haven't given us the complete XAML layout, but I suspect your data model may be one level too complex. In other words, consider flattening your data tree.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I was taken ill for a few days. I realise my questions wasn't entirely clear but I think you nailed it when you said you suspect my data model is one level too deep. I'm going to brush up some more on MVVM and re-think/refactor some things. Thanks for the pointers.